# Difference between a class snippet and an object snippet

Tags: class, scala, object, lift

I would like to know what is the exact difference between a class snippet and an object snippet in lift.

If I have

```
class Foo {
  var a: String
  def render(n:NodeSeq) = {
    <h3> you chose {a} </h3>
  }
}
```

and

```
object Bar {
  var b: String
  def render(n:NodeSeq) = {
    <h3> you chose {b} </h3>
  }
}
```

What is the concrete difference between them, do `a` and `b` have a different behaviour. 
In [simply lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.4.html#toc-Subsection-3.4.4) it is said that

> In this case, the snippet is an object singleton because it does not take any constructor parameters and has no instance variabled.

So does it mean that for every user, `Bar` will be the same?

I know that it is a noob question, however I need to be very clear on this and I don't match well the difference between objects and classes in snippets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/More_on_Snippets).

Basically, a new instance of Foo will be created for each http request (so there will be many existing at the same time), but only one instance of Bar will ever exist at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly the little hint I needed!

Answer (score -2):

An object is an instance of a class. In this case you can just define an object straight away. In lets say C++/Java etc you have to make a class first and then instantiate it. It simplifies i.e. when you need to make a singleton class, which you'd need to do some kind of design pattern to handle in other object oriented languages that does not support the object construct.

To further differentiate the two consider the class the blueprint of a house and the object the actual house.

Comment: Hi, I understand the concept of object and class, it is just that, applied to snippets and liftweb, I'm getting lost in what the user gets.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Assuming you pasted in all the relevant code, that is the difference between the two. One you need to instantiate to use, and the other you don't. They would behave differently because the functions are defined differently. But yes every access to Bar would call the same code. It's a singleton. Calling the same method on two different instances of Foo would also run the same code, only with different "this" references